# Rails methods called as symbols when used as parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, symbols

I'm working on the Rails Tutorial (rails 4) by Michael Hartl, and I'm confused about how `symbols` are used. I understand why `symbols` are used for `hashes`, but I don't know why they are used to refer to methods. For example, in the code below, there's a method called `signed_in_user` defined, which is called as `:signed_in_user` when passed to `before_action`. Same goes for `:edit` and `:update`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  .
  .
  .
  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the interface of `Object#send` in ruby 2.1 you will find the `symbol` variant first and the `string` variant second, but up to ruby 2.0 there used to be *only* the `symbol` variant! As all methods will be passed through `#send` it made sense to use its parameter wherever you referred to a method in order to avoid constant calls to `#to_sym` everywhere. I do not know why this change was introduced, but I guess the `symbols` will stick around for some time, at least they are one character less to type :-)

That goes without saying that symbols are allocated only once throughout a program, they will not be garbage collected and are therefore slightly more efficient than strings. As processors still get faster more quickly than RAM I guess the distinction has become less important lately.

As you can see in the [discussion of new features of ruby 2.1](http://globaldev.co.uk/2014/05/ruby-2-1-in-detail/) the difference between symbols and frozen strings is becoming less. Frozen strings are now only allocated once, symbols are now frozen and there is even a hint about symbols possibly being garbage collected in the future. This would eventually eliminate an attack vector for a denial of service attack if external data is turned into symbols. On the other hand, `def` and `define_method` now return the names of the methods they define as symbols (instead of returning `nil` as they used to).

Comment: this `but up to ruby 2.0 there used to be only the symbol variant!` wrong! be carefull with your opinion.

Comment: ? thats what I found in [The Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) ?? Could you elaborate?

Comment: http://repl.it/V51 1.8.7 `send()` accept `symbol/string` arguments in any version.

Comment: I guess you are right at this point, while the docs *stated* only symbols, the actual methods *always* did turn their arguments into symbols as the docs for ruby 2.1 do state now. Sloppy docs then and stupid me to trust them anyways.

Answer (score 1):

**Symbols**

What you need to know is how Ruby treats [`:symbols`](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm) - I don't know exactly, but it's basically a way to denote a piece of data:

> There are elements of truth in each of the preceding assertions, and
>   yet in my opinion they are not valuable, partially because they depend
>   on a deep knowledge of Ruby to understand their significance. I prefer
>   to answer the question "what are symbols" in a language independent
>   manner:
>
> A Ruby symbol is a thing that has both a number (integer)
>   representation and a string representation.

They are generally used (in my experience) for providing you with the ability to populate an object with a piece of data, that can either be "raw" data (string / integer), a method name, or object.

You'll typically use `symbols` when denoting `arguments`, which looks like the case here

--

**Callbacks**

The [`before_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) method in your controller is what's known as a *callback* (I think)

Callbacks are used to give you a way to control the data-flow of the application, without intruding in the actual process itself. For example, [`before_save` callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) can be called to perform actions on objects ready to be saved, without interfering with the save process itself

With your `before_action` callback, the arguments Rails needs are as follows:

[image]

So essentially, your passing of a `method name` as a `symbol` means Ruby can read it for what it is, instead of having to work out whether it's a "string" etc

That's my interpretation